# Generating application using Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to generate an application/joining/or any info letter using Django in which some of the values will be retrevied from the database.
I want to have

```
Current_Date
To
Address(to be retreived from database)
Subject
Matter
Some names of members(to be retreivedfrom database according to what user selects
1.aa
2.bb
```

How should I do this. Have created the models for it like

```
class address(models.Model):
    street=model.CharField(maxlength=500)
    and so on.
```

But how to have models for members?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(maxlength=500)
```